# With multiple checkboxes, how to make a product selector?

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, checkbox

I'm working on a project for school in which I need to make a product selector using jQuery!
But unfortunately I can't make it work!

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/rda9Q/2/

As you can see, at the beginning, I need all the product to be showed in a div;
then when we check check1, all the different products are hidden to show the list of product with the attribute check1;
the same with check2;
and then (most important part) when both are checked, to show a different list of product with the two attributes!

I'm not sure but I think the problem is in that part:

```
function myFunction()
  {
if ($("#check1").is(':checked'))
  {
  $(".results").hide();
  $("#check1result").show();
  }
}

function myFunction()
{
if ($("#check2").is(':checked'))
  {
  $(".results").hide();
  $("#check2result").show();
  }
}

function myFunction()
{
if ($("#check1").is(':checked'), $("#check2").is(':checked'))
  {
 $(".results").hide();
  $("#check1et2result").show();
  }
}
```

But I just can't find it!

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: Do u want to see totally a different set of products when selecting check1 and check2 or a combination of both check1 and check2 results?

Comment: I just want to see a specific div in which i mixed all the products manually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only define myFunction() once. Also without myFunction(), you can use jquery click event. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rda9Q/4/

Also do not forget to include the jquery library on the left hand side menu.

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">Check1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2">Check2<br>
<button id="button">Filter</button>
<div id="mainresult" class="results">
<p>All the products</p>
</div>
<div id="check1result" class="results" style="display:none;">
<p>The products with the specific spec Check1</p>
</div>
<div id="check2result" class="results" style="display:none;">
<p>The products with the specific spec Check2</p>
</div>
<div id="check1et2result" class="results" style="display:none;">
<p>Products with both specs Check 1 and 2</p>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
 $('#button').on('click',function(){
    if($("#check1").is(':checked') && $("#check2").is(':checked')){
         $(".results").hide();
           $("#check1result").show();
           $("#check2result").show();
        /*
          OR IF YOU STILL WANT TO USE SPECIFIC DIV FOR BOTH RESULTS
          $("#check1et2result").show();
        */   
    }
     else if ($("#check1").is(':checked'))
      {
          $(".results").hide();
          $("#check1result").show();
      }
     else if ($("#check2").is(':checked'))
      {
          $(".results").hide();
          $("#check2result").show();
      }
    else{
        $(".results").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Caner! I'm new to this stuff and you gave me a very big help :)

Answer (score 0):

So many typos and errors:

1. `myFunction` can be defined one with all the logic without define it third
2. `$("#check1).is(':checked'))` have a syntax error, check the browser console is your friend for life
3. the and operator is `&&` not `,`
4. you can register a click handler in jQuery instead of inline onclick, and so on

Check out the basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript and here http://learn.jquery.com

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
    $(".results").show();
    $("#check1et2result, #check1result, #check2result").hide();
    if ($("#check1").is(':checked') && $("#check2").is(':checked')) {
        $(".results").hide();
        $("#check1et2result").show();
    } else {
        if ($("#check1").is(':checked')) {
            $(".results").hide();
            $("#check1result").show();
        }
        if ($("#check2").is(':checked')) {
            $(".results").hide();
            $("#check2result").show();
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DBEww/

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips of myFunction and operator!

Answer (score 0):

You can try also to make some action directly on checkbox change, without button like following:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checkbox">Check1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="checkbox">Check2<br>

<div id="mainresult" class="results all">
<p>All the products</p>
</div>
<div id="check1result" class="results check1" style="display:none;">
<p>The products with the specific spec Check1</p>
</div>
<div id="check2result" class="results check2" style="display:none;">
<p>The products with the specific spec Check2</p>
</div>
<div id="check1et2result" class="results check1check2" style="display:none;">
<p>Products with both specs Check 1 and 2</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    var className = '';
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        className += $(this).attr('id');
    });

    if(className.length == 0)
        className = 'all';

    $('div').hide();
    $('div.' + className).show();
});
```

Fiddle ->> http://jsfiddle.net/rda9Q/5/